# AlertDialog sends no callback when created

Tags: android, callback, android-alertdialog

I have this simple code:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

dialog.setTitle ("Alert title");
dialog.setMessage ("This is an alert");

dialog.show();
```

The dialog is shown but my Activity receives no callbacks. No onPrepareDialog, nothing.

Can I somehow hook AlertDialog without implementing a custom class extending AlertDialog?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onPrepareDialog` is only called for dialogs managed by an Activity (i.e. dialogs created and returned with `Activity.onCreateDialog(int)` and shown via `Activity.showDialog(int)`). Since you are creating and showing a dialog directly, these methods will not be called.

See [Creating Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) for more information on managed dialogs.

To respond to use input - like button clicks - you'll want to use the builder methods as demonstrated by alezhka's answer.

Comment: The problem is I'm again have to hack a 3rd party closed code. As a temporary solution I wrote my own versions of AlertDialog and substituted all the references from SMALI code to my versions.

Comment: No you don't. Read the link provided by Dave. You are just using the wrong method. If you want these functions invoked, use `showDialog()`, `onCreateDialog()` and so on.

Comment: I cannot use showDialog() ... otherwise I would not call for help. The code is closed and I cannot rewrite what I want. I may only do some limited SMALI editing and add my own classes. The original code uses very short sequence which results in a dialog not owned by Activity.

Comment: Well, thats an important detail that's nowhere to be found in your question. Ask good questions if you want good answers.

Comment: More here: the top idea is to add a custom transparent View with some additional information for every single panel in the Application. For main and sub-Views, for Menus, for Dialogs...

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog dialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Alert title").setMessage("This is an alert");
builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new Dialog.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

}
});
dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: You can merge the last 2 lines by calling `builder.show()`. That creates and shows the dialog in one step.

Comment: That is more or less resembles what I have in the code. But when the dialog is shown or dismissed, Activity receives no callback. (I'm under Froyo 2.2 API 8).

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog alertDialog;    
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage("your message");
    builder.setTitle("Alert message");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```